# How to implement flag for execution of abstract PHP method?

Tags: php, abstract

I have part of abstract base class that looks like this:

```
abstract class Fragment_Cache {

    static $in_callback = false;

    abstract public function callback( $name, $args );
}
```

I need to flip `$in_callback` to `true` during `callback()` method execution. That is used in other part of code to prevent nesting of caches (so I want to cache widget and menu, but not menu inside widget).

However since it is abstract method I cannot rely on subclass implementations for that.

I also cannot flip flag on/off around method call, because it is passed on and executed by different library that takes care of running it async instead of during page load.

How can I architecture myself out of this corner? :)

Actual monstrosity that sets up its call:

```
$output = tlc_transient( 'fragment-cache-' . $this->type . '-' . $name . $salt )
            ->updates_with( array( $this, 'callback' ), array( $name, $args ) )
            ->expires_in( $this->timeout )->get();
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how is this method used in your code?

Comment: @OneTrickPony added how call is set up to question

Comment: And you can't change `array( $this, 'callback' )` with let's say  `array( $this, 'wrappingCallback' )` ?

Comment: @OneTrickPony I was thinking in that direction and answers trend there as well. Will test this approach out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about hiding the actual functionality in another function?

```
abstract class Fragment_Cache {

    static $in_callback = false;

    public function callback($name, $args)
    {
        self::$in_callback = true;
        $this->doCallback($name, $args);
        self::$in_callback = false;
    }

    abstract protected function doCallback( $name, $args );
}
```

You need to overwrite `doCallback`, which will do the actual heavy-lifting, but is not accessible directly from the outside, only via `callback`.

Comment: within 4 keystrokes that is identical to what I was about to post

Comment: If functions are not solving your problem you have not created enough of them. :) Seems to work peachy! Although I do need return there and maybe to `final` wrapper to that subclasses don't mess with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class Fragment_Cache {

    static $in_callback = false;

    public function callback( $name, $args ){
        self::$in_callback = true;
        $ret = $this->__doCallback($name, $args);
        self::$in_callback = false;
        return $ret;
    }

    abstract protected function __doCallback($name, $args);
}
```

Comment: The difference is saving the return value from the inner function.